# Find the name of application from ip address

Tags: android, ios, ip, appdomain

In my project I have lots of ip addresses which are getting from a smartphone and I should categorize this ip according to which application used them.Is there any service to find the name of application from the ip addresses.

Comment: The answer is __NO__. and there won't be any

Comment: @bansi could yo explain more why wont be.I am not very wise in this area.Thanks a lot

Comment: because IP address is no way connected to an application. it is the address of the device. The only thing you can do is when something connects to your server you can keep track to which application it connected and from which IP

Comment: @bansi ok but for example I want to block whatsapp .In order to do this which ip adresses I should block.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/695621/how-to-block-the-whatsapp-android-application-in-a-network